# How to get object file to link first?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile a Windows DLL for code originally intended for a Unix platform. One problem I have is that Windows `fopen()` defaults to `O_TEXT`, but Unix defaults to `O_BINARY`.
Windows recommends two ways to solve this:

1. Use `_set_fmode()` function, didn't work for me probably because I could not call it from correct context.
2. Link with `binmode.obj` object file. This file is included with the compiler, and the compiler knows where to look for it.

The latter worked for my own code, but it does not seem to work for third party static libraries. Looking at the linker output, I can see that static libraries are included before `binmode.obj`, but `binmode.obj` was included before my own object files.
The real solution should be to persuade all external libraries to include `binmode.obj`, but this is somewhat non-trivial and might incur significant maintenance overhead in the future.
So I'd like to try to move the `binmode.obj` to the beginning of the linker command line, but this proved to be surprisingly difficult. I've tried:

1. `target_link_libraries( mylib PRIVATE binmode.obj )` - Got correct position, but got renamed to `binmode.obj.lib` casuing linker error.
2. Tried making a static library with `binmode.obj` as a pre-compiled object, but got an error that the file has a relative path. I have no idea how to make it a full path.
3. Tried adding it as a linker flag in different ways, even including using toolchain file, but it all ended up with `binmode.obj` being placed after libraries.

I'm now out of ideas and feel I need help with this. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: An imported object library may work, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries

Comment: Object library didn't work, since if I give the object file as source file I get complaints about using relative path, and if I try property `IMPORTED_LOCATION` it seems to be ignored since nothing really happened. However, when reading documentation about this property, I did notice `UNKNOWN` library works with it. I tried that and it worked! So thanks for setting me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

@fabian's comment made me read the right part of CMake documentation, which made me realize that UNKNOWN library type could be used. Using the following code in CMake I could make binmode.obj appear before all libraries:

```
add_library( binmode_obj UNKNOWN IMPORTED GLOBAL )
set_target_properties( binmode_obj PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION binmode.obj )
target_link_libraries( mylib PUBLIC binmode_obj )
```

This solved my problem of trying out if link binmode.obj before libraries might fix my original problem. It didn't, unfortunately. But that is another problem...